# Functions are not run synchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 4 functions, `calculateSingle, calculateAll, process` and `save`.

`process` calls a service which saves my recalculated values and should always happen after `calculateAll` has finished. This doesn't happen in my case. Somehow `save` decides to run even about 4ms before all the `calculateSingle` calls do.

This is my approach. I pass the `save` function as a callback to the `calculateAll` function. Please consider this pseudo code I've written.

```js
$scope.calculateSingle = function() {
  //call web service to calculate single row in a table
}

$scope.calculateAll = function(callback) {
  var promises = [];

  for(var i in numberOfRows) {
    promises.push($scope.calculateSingle(i));
  }

  //combine promises to call calculateSingle as many times as there are rows
  $q.all(promises).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
      //take the response and apply all the recalculated values onto view
    }
  ).then(
    //SHOULD BE CALLED AFTER CALCULATE IS FINISHED AND VALUES ARE REASSIGNED
    //This is the $scope.save() function passes as a callback function
    if(callback) {
      callback();
    }
  );
}

$scope.process = function() {
  $scope.calculateAll($scope.save());
}

$scope.save = function() {
  //run the save
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.save()` calls save immediately; if you want to pass it as a callback, you should use `$scope.save`

```
$scope.process = function() {
  $scope.calculateAll($scope.save);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That was a great lesson for me even though it may sound stupid not to know that.